# static IP on vbox bridged network for ubuntu (guest) on ubuntu (host)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Network Connection error & can't browse internet, how do I troubleshoot the network connection? I want to set a static IP for vbox guest ubuntu 12.04 machine on bridged network Host is ubuntu 12.04.

steps i did:

on vbox, I enabled bridged network & in ubuntu host's network interface I added a new wired connection with following info:

`IP : 192.168.8.8 
netmask: 255.255.255.0 
gateway/DNS:192.168.1.1`

in my host  cat /etc/network/interfaces (i did a gedit to append the static IP info)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.8.8
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.1.1
```

in my guest  cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

> IP : 192.168.8.8 netmask: 255.255.255.0 gateway/DNS:192.168.1.1

This is not going to work. Your IP is not in the same subnet than the default gateway. Either use a IP in the correct network (i.e. 192.168.0.8) or change the network mask to 255.255.0.0, whatever is appropriate for your network configuration.

If you give us some working machine configuration we can deduce the correct option.